# How do I use `ts` (timestamp) command in msys2/mingw

Tags: windows, mingw, msys

I have some problem with zsh, I need `ts` to log the execution time .

```
zsh -xv 2>&1 | ts -i "%.s" > zsh_startup.log
```

But

```
zsh: command not found: ts
```

`pacman -Ss ts` got a lot of unrelevernt result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ts` command seems to be included in [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/). Try

```
$ pacman -S msys/moreutils
```

Test:

```
$ ts
foo
Jan 11 12:29:20 foo
bar
Jan 11 12:29:23 bar
```

Comment: Thanks, how did you find this ? I google get nothing.

Comment: That `ts` turned up in a couple of man pages, the only clue there was the author, but this led to nothing. Then I googled for "ts timestamp command linux" and got this hit https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26797/43298. ` pacman -Ss moreutils` then displayed two packages, among them the above one.